# Xamarin forms resx localization always return default language

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization, resx

My Xamarin forms resx localization always return default language after visual studio update.

Current version is visual studio 16.9.5 and I tried 16.10 Preview version but it had the same bug.

My AppResources.resx file setting

```
Build action: Embedded Resource
Custom tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
```

and other AppResources.ko.resx and AppResources.ja.resx file setting

```
Build action: Embedded Resource
```

The workaround below has already been applied but not working to me.
(https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4664#issuecomment-632986668)

Please help me.. I spent almost two days into this bug..

---------------------------------- Add ---------------------------------------

My main project's name is 'Core'.

My resx files are in 'Core/Properties/' (ex] Core/Properties/AppResources.resx').

Default language is 'en' and I have also 'AppResources.ko.resx' and 'AppResources.ja.resx' in the same path as AppResources.resx.

Comment: Try to change the `Custom tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` to `Custom tool: ResXFileCodeGenerator`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Not working to me :(

Comment: Could you share a sample which can reproduce this issue ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

The problem is from the latest visual studio version and the previous workaround (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4664#issuecomment-632986668)

The previous workaround propose to modify Android project .csproj file as belows

```
 <Target Name="_ResolveSatellitePaths"
DependsOnTargets="_ResolveAssemblies">
<ResolveAssemblyReference
    AllowedAssemblyExtensions="$(AllowedReferenceAssemblyFileExtensions)"
    AssemblyFiles="@(ResolvedUserAssemblies)"
    AutoUnify="$(AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences)"
    FindDependencies="True"
    FindRelatedFiles="False"
    FindSatellites="True"
    SearchPaths="$(AssemblySearchPaths)"
    TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)"
    TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName="$(TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName)"
    TargetFrameworkDirectories="$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)">
  <Output TaskParameter="SatelliteFiles" ItemName="_AndroidResolvedSatellitePaths"/>
</ResolveAssemblyReference>
```

But, after updating visual studio, this workaround has created the problem.

I erased this code, and all works well!